# What is the difference between Re-installing Microsoft Office on the same computer again vs. another PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-office, license, software-activation

Reinstalling my OS.

Will I have any trouble reinstalling Office 2010 with the same key on the same PC?

Is there a difference between installing it on a second PC vs. what I am doing?

(does reactivation on the same PC differ from a different PC?)

Is it true a key really works unlimited times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. The main difference is that you don't have two copies of Office installed *at the same time*.

I've reinstalled Office a few times now on different hardware and OS's (XP and now 7) without any problems.

If you do get problems ring Microsoft and explain you are reinstalling after an upgrade/reinstallation and they should unlock it for you.

I don't know whether the key really works for an unlimited number of times, but I suspect that there is a check on how frequently you are reactivating it. If you reactivate every day (say) then I would expect that to cause problems.

Comment: A lot of retail Office packs actually ALLOW two installations (only two, though).  It should say.

Comment: @Shinrai - that's on a desktop and a laptop (though how they tell I don't know). The idea being that you're still only using one at a time.

Comment: @ChrisF - That's the intended use, you're exactly right, but I believe the fine print doesn't really care.  I've certainly never heard of anybody having trouble.  I'm assuming this is because there IS no easy way to tell.

Comment: @Shinrai: The fine print **does care**.  It's the software implementation that does not prevent you from using two installs simultaneously.